# Production logging for Java app

Tags: java, logging

There is inherent tension between logging verbosity and performance of Java app in production. If we log very selectively then we might miss evidences for issues in production to debug . If we add too much logging in production , can impact performance.

I was thinking along the line with couple of options :

1. Log all selective and important things
2. Have SSDs instead of hard disks in prod
3. Have logging utility that can "batch" logging statements and flush periodically
4. Have some utility that will hold logs in memory and then flush eventually.

What are best approaches other than outlined above ? Are there any existing logging tools that can be used for this purpose ?

Comment: What's the difference between 3 and 4? Where is the "batch" held if not in memory?

Comment: Sorry I mean in 3 to develop mechanism in our code and 4 means to have such utility available already that can be used

Answer (score 0):

Try apache log4j with slf4j( you can switch log4j without much changes in your code). Use the configuration xml to provide what to log and which files to log.
Also use rolling file appenders and buffer appenders to handle flushing and batching of logs.